# Rancher Etcd inner db cannot clean

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, etcd

have a Rancher installation using docker image. version v2.2.1.

Lately started to get logs “Failed to update lock: etcdserver: mvcc: database space exceeded”

checking etcd for the cluster we have everything looks ok.

[etcd status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puu8B.png)

So noticed that etcd db inside rancher docker container is like this:

inside directoy /var/lib/rancher/management-state/etcd/member/snap

2.1G Jul 17 22:29 db

but cannot compact or interact with it.

Why Rancher docker image has a etcd db itself? is not enough having the cluster one?

and how can we keep it small in order to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Same here with single node installation of rancher/rancher:stable (997af25b7b54). 
You can run etcdctl in a service container on the same docker host like your rancher:

```
docker run --net=container:<NAME_OF_RANCHER_CONTAINER> -id --name etcd-utility rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.40
```

And then, because you use the net from the rancher container, the localhost output here refers to the rancher container.

```
docker exec etcd-utility etcdctl member list
8e9e05c52164694d: name=default peerURLs=http://localhost:2380
clientURLs=http://localhost:2379 isLeader=true
```

Now, when attaching to the etcd-utils container, you can fix the issue with your etcd like this (no output pasted):

```
host# docker exec -it etcd-utility bash

bash-4.4# export ETCDCTL_API=3
bash-4.4# etcdctl endpoint status --endpoints=$(etcdctl member list | cut -d, -f5 | sed -e 's/ //g' | paste -sd ',') --write-out table
bash-4.4# etcdctl compact `etcdctl endpoint status --write-out json | egrep -o '"revision":[0-9]*' | egrep -o '[0-9]*'`
bash-4.4# etcdctl defrag  `etcdctl endpoint status --write-out json | egrep -o '"revision":[0-9]*' | egrep -o '[0-9]*'`
bash-4.4# etcdctl alarm list
bash-4.4# etcdctl alarm disarm
```

The latter follows the etcd trouble shooting guide for cluster etcd, which is explained in detail in the rancher docs [etcd-space-errors](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/troubleshooting/kubernetes-components/#etcd-space-errors). For single node, see [links in this comment](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/15856#issuecomment-521984762)

Comment: super helpful, but when running those commands with rke-tools v0.1.40 results in "No help topic for 'endpoint'" I'm guessing that version of etcdctl doesnt have the "endpoint status" or comact/defrag commands. Have you seen this?

Comment: nevermind,v2.2 in the link that you pasted solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: help on endpoints and compact as well as defrag is available with ETCDCTL_API=3 I've fixed the line, thanks! @Ryan please flag this question as solved then.

Comment: Not my question or I totally would! I upvoted though.